# does not name type error when trying to make class template

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I am getting this error >> does not name type error `does not name type`when I try to run make for the files. I tried looking everywhere but can't find how to fix it. Please help!

**templateex.cpp**

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <assert.h>

template<class T>
templateex<T>::templateex()
{
    cout<<"Constructor Executing"<<endl;

    noValidEntries=0;
}
```

**templateex.h**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define SIZE 20

template <class T> class templateex
{
public:
   templateex();                     // default constructor

};
#include "templateex.cpp"
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "templateex.h"   
int main()
{ 
templateex<int>example;
}
```

**ERROR**

```
templateex.cpp:5:1: error: 'templateex' does not name a type
```

Comment: You constructor should be `templateex()` and in template.cpp it should be `templateex::templateex()`

Comment: thats how it was i just fixed it. for some reason spell check put it to temple. I am still getting the error

Comment: Also, why are you `#include`-ing template.cpp in template.h?  And in your main.cpp you need to declare `templateex<int> example;`  You seem to lack fundamental understanding of templated classes, so I would recommend reading this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part

Comment: Including a cpp file is bound to be a problem at some point.  You should use a different extension if you insist on implementing it in a different file.

Comment: Your class is named `templateex`.  If the code you posted is inaccurate, please edit.

Comment: What the heck is `templateex <class T>`?

Comment: i fixed the class but still have an error

Comment: Why are you `#include`-ing templateex.cpp in your header file?

Comment: I thought that would bring the function from the cpp file to the header

Comment: nope. You need to include the header in the .cpp.  That's what "brings them together"

Answer (score 0):

Templateex.h

```
#ifndef MY_TEMPLATEEX_H
#define MY_TEMPLATEEX_H

template <class T>
class Templateex
{
public:
    Templateex();

private:
    int noValidEntries_;
};

#include "Templateex.inl"
#endif
```

Templateex.inl

```
#ifndef MY_TEMPLATEEX_INL
#define MY_TEMPLATEEX_INL

#include<iostream>

template <class T>
Templateex<T>::Templateex()
{
    std::cout << "Constructor Executing" << std::endl;
    noValidEntries_ = 0;
}

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Templateex.h"

int main()
{
    Templateex<int> example;
}
```

1. compilers need to see templates' definition when they are instantiated, essentially require a template be contained in one header file. However, It is a good style to separate a template class definition from its declaration, especially for complex definitions. Hence the "#include Templateex.inl".
2. usually a template definition file (essentially a header file) should not use the "cpp" extension, because many tools (e.g. GNU make) by default assume "*.cpp" files are source files, *.inl is a good name for this purpose.
3. use #ifndef #define ... #endif to guard against multiple inclusions.
4. do not "using namespace std" in header files, always use fully qualified names. What the "using.." does is to make all names in "namespace std" available. Since a header file may be included in many different compilation unit, export names in a namespace in a header file pollute other namespaces.  use of "using namespace ... " should be confined in a single compilation unit, i.e. in source file only.
5. you didn't declare variable "noValidEntries"...